# smplayer doesn't play video when mplayer does

Tags: matroska, mplayer, nvidia-graphics-card, vdpau

I just installed mplayer with [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/mplayer) and smplayer with [this one](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/smplayer). I put the following in my ~.mplayer/config:

```
vo=vdpau
vc=ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau,
```

Now, mplayer works like a charm and vdpau is working, my cpu never goes above 6%.  So I figured smplayer would be a nice gui for mplayer, and figured it would play the video the same way mplayer would (since it's just a frontend) but I get no video at all.  What am I missing here?  Do I need to do something different to get smplayer to play my mkv's?

Comment: If you look at the output of `ps x`, what is the mplayer command that smplayer is running?

Comment: thanks for that tip, it was running with vo=vx.  Sunny's suggestion worked, I had to tell smplayer to run with the vdpau driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the proper options in smplayer. If you not see them in the GUI, then, in the Advanced section you can add arbitrary options to be passed to mplayer.

Comment: I guess I just assumed it would take my .mplayer config, obviously not.  Adjusting the video driver from vx do vdpau worked!  Thanks a bunch!